# <form> HTML tag stopping my devise form from working?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, devise, bootstrap-4

The HTML  tag is stopping my devise sign up form from submitting.

When I take the tag away, everything works as intended. There are no errors appearing.

```
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="field"
                      <%= f.label :username %>
                      <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Username" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="field">
                      <%= f.label :email %>
                      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="field">
                      <%= f.label :password %>
                      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
                      <% end %><br />
                      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="field">
                      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
                      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password Confirmation" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="actions" style="padding-top: 2%">
                      <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "site-btn btn-sm centered" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
              </div>
                <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
          </div>
        </form>
```

I don't know if I'm missing something silly or if this a known problem? Please help! :-)

Comment: What <form> tag are you talking about? The one generated by `form_for`? Is this the standard view created by Devise? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @bo-oz the <form> tag at the top of the code I included. The problem is that my form won't submit when the <form> is there, but I need the <form> tag to make the bootstrap styles work :(

Comment: @MeganRalph I recommend editing your question with that information (that it won't submit, and which form tag you mean). It will make it easier for people to answer it.

Comment: You can't nest FORM tags, move the `.form-group` and `.row` divs inside the `form_for` block.

Answer (score 1):

the `</form>` down your code might be the problem. and you don't need the `<form>` tag anymore since rails form produces html form on the browser.

```
          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
            <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
              <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="field"
                  <%= f.label :username %>
                  <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Username" %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="field">
                  <%= f.label :email %>
                  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email" %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="field">
                  <%= f.label :password %>
                  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                  <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
                  <% end %><br />
                  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password" %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="field">
                  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
                  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password Confirmation" %>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="actions" style="padding-top: 2%">
                  <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "site-btn btn-sm centered" %>
                </div>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
            <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the code you have right now in the browser, you will see that you have two form tags. The one you put with `<form>` and one generated by `form_for...` by Rails. Remove the `<form>` tag and it will work.

If you want bootstrap styles to work on the forms generated by Rails I recommend the simple_form_for gem
http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/documentation

It is a bit tricky to get used to in the beginning, but it works fantastic :)